# HashRouter tips error in react router 4.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

Next to the Web Tips Picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2OGn.png

```
Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

Tips error , This is when I click on the link again

---

Next to Picture is React-Router File Code...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgqqN.png

```
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Provider } from  'react-redux';
import View from './containers';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const AppRouter = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <View.App.Container>
                <Route path='/' exact={true} component={View.App.Dashboard} />
                <Route path='/Todo' component={View.Todo.Container} />
                <Route path='/News' render={() => (
                    <View.News.Container>
                        <Route path='/News/List' render={() => (
                            <h2>News List Show</h2>
                            )} />
                    </View.News.Container>
                )} />
            </View.App.Container>
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use the component Link for navigation, you may want to set the prop `replace` on it.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/replace-bool

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Be careful. This'll cause your browser can not navigate previous route when you clicked the back button.